# Server SIde My code Not working

Tags: php, paypal

I have integrated paypal with php. its Working in xampp Localhost. after that My code move to server its showing error Like this ?

> Warning: require_once(E:\web\dotnetpo/Abaceu/lms/conf.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in E:\web\dotnetpo\Project\Abaceu\shopping_cart\paypal.php
>   on line 42
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'E:\web\dotnetpo/Abaceu/lms/conf.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\pear\pear') in
>   E:\web\dotnetpo\Project\Abaceu\shopping_cart\paypal.php on line 42

How to Resolve this error?

Comment: Do you know the difference between absolute and relative paths?

Comment: @Blaatpraat  what u means saying?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
E:\web\dotnetpo/Abaceu/lms/conf.php
```

to

```
E:\web\dotnetpo\Abaceu\lms\conf.php
```

I think it's a problem with '\' and it causes the directory issue.

Comment: I would like to see the files hierarchy to help you.